# which way to create a soft link on XP or Vista for projects?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-xp, symlink

I'd like to create a soft link on XP and Vista so that

c:\proj01\lib  will point to c:\lib

and

c:\proj02\lib  will point to c:\lib

the reason to do so is that some IDE has auto complete to suggest the function name or can quick jump to the function in different files, but all files must be under one folder, such as c:\proj01, so I hope to create a soft link c:\proj01\lib that will point to c:\lib

on XP and Vista, what's the best way to create such links?  thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

mklink doesn't exist on XP, but you can use Sysinternals' [Junction tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx)

Comment: If this is the correct answer, the question must be wrong... Junction only creates and shows hard links, not soft links.

Answer (score 4):

From a terminal: mklink /D {linkname} {targetdir}